# sending MQTT data to server by phone itself i.e without using setOnClickListener() or any other event

Tags: android, mqtt

I am sending the data to [wso2 IOT server](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/About+WSO2+IoT+Server) from android phone using [this sample code](https://github.com/wso2/samples-iots/tree/master/AndroidMQTTSample) and its working fine when I send data manually form text box as shown below.

[image]

The issue is that  I am not able to send data when the activity starts. I want to do this because later on phone will listen to some events, then filter then using CEP and send filtered events to IOT server. However, I am stuck with this first step i.e sending some data w/o taking it from user to IOT server.

I tried to send data in `onStart()` in RegisteredActivity class

```
@Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();


                String message = "custom message";

                try {
                    deviceManagementService.publishMessage(message);
                } catch (TransportHandlerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The error is that in this case, the Application does not even start

Any help will be highly appreciated

---

### Edit 1

code of `RegisteredActivity class` is

```
public class RegisteredActivity extends Activity {

    private DeviceManagementService deviceManagementService;
    private boolean isBound = false;

    private ServiceConnection deviceManagementServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            DeviceManagementService.LocalBinder binder = (DeviceManagementService.LocalBinder) service;
            deviceManagementService = binder.getService();
            isBound = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            isBound = false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registered);



        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceManagementService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);



        final Button btnDisconnect = findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnect);
        btnDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                unregister();
            }
        });


        final EditText txtPayload = findViewById(R.id.editTextPayload);

        final Button btnPublish = findViewById(R.id.btnPublish);
        btnPublish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isBound) {
                    try {
                        String message = "wowww";

//                        deviceManagementService.publishMessage(message);
                        deviceManagementService.publishMessage(txtPayload.getText().toString());
                    } catch (TransportHandlerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceManagementService.class);
        bindService(intent, deviceManagementServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (isBound) {
            unbindService(deviceManagementServiceConnection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        String message = "costom message";

        try {
            deviceManagementService.publishMessage(message);
        } catch (TransportHandlerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void unregister() {
        if (!LocalRegistry.isExist(getApplicationContext())) {
            Intent activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(activity);
        }
        LocalRegistry.removeUsername(getApplicationContext());
        LocalRegistry.removeDeviceId(getApplicationContext());
        LocalRegistry.removeServerURL(getApplicationContext());
        LocalRegistry.removeAccessToken(getApplicationContext());
        LocalRegistry.removeRefreshToken(getApplicationContext());
        LocalRegistry.removeMqttEndpoint(getApplicationContext());
        LocalRegistry.setExist(false);

        //Stop current running background services.
        Intent myService = new Intent(this, DeviceManagementService.class);
        stopService(myService);

        Intent registerActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
        registerActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(registerActivity);
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Error is**

```
02-02 05:13:21.611 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample E/MQTTTransportHandler: MQTT Client Error whilst client [null:sample] tried to publish to queue at [tcp://192.168.56.1:1886] under topic [carbon.super/sample/null/events]
02-02 05:13:21.615 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err: org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.mqtt.transport.TransportHandlerException: MQTT Client Error whilst client [null:sample] tried to publish to queue at [tcp://192.168.56.1:1886] under topic [carbon.super/sample/null/events]
02-02 05:13:21.623 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.mqtt.transport.MQTTTransportHandler.publishToQueue(MQTTTransportHandler.java:285)
02-02 05:13:21.623 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.mqtt.transport.MQTTTransportHandler.publishToQueue(MQTTTransportHandler.java:242)
02-02 05:13:21.623 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.mqtt.MQTTHandler.publishDeviceData(MQTTHandler.java:161)
02-02 05:13:21.623 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.services.DeviceManagementService.publishMessage(DeviceManagementService.java:71)
02-02 05:13:21.623 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.RegisteredActivity$3.onClick(RegisteredActivity.java:87)
02-02 05:13:21.624 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
02-02 05:13:21.624 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
02-02 05:13:21.624 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
02-02 05:13:21.624 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 05:13:21.624 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
02-02 05:13:21.624 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
02-02 05:13:21.625 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-02 05:13:21.626 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
02-02 05:13:21.626 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err: Caused by: Client is not connected (32104)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms.sendNoWait(ClientComms.java:143)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.publish(MqttAsyncClient.java:858)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.publish(MqttClient.java:361)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.publish(MqttClient.java:353)
02-02 05:13:21.629 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:     at org.wso2.iot.mqttsample.mqtt.transport.MQTTTransportHandler.publishToQueue(MQTTTransportHandler.java:278)
02-02 05:13:21.630 12135-12135/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample W/System.err:    ... 13 more
02-02 05:13:24.679 12135-12155/org.wso2.iot.mqttsample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9aad160: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8e6481c0)
```

Comment: can you share rest of your `RegisteredActivity` code and error log?

Comment: @global_warming : I have made edit in original post, Thanks in adv for looking into this problem.

Comment: try moving code after binding service, as `onStart` is called before `onResume` and you are publishing message while client is not connected to broker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to publish events automatically you can use Siddhi Sinks. You can define a Siddhi Sink for an output event stream. A Siddhi Sink has publish method. You can write your own Siddhi Sink by extending the Sink class. Whenever an output event stream get triggered, you can publish those events using Siddhi Sinks. 
Additionally to DeviceManagementService class, you can use a SiddhiService class to execute the Siddhi App.

Siddhi Sink - https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#sink

Also you can see one of my implementation of Siddhi inside Android here - https://github.com/Gathika94/EdgeComputingGateway_Android.
In this implementation I have implemented what you wanted using a customized Siddhi Sink.